# Sorting and querying documents in couchbase-lite android

Tags: android, couchbase, couchbase-lite, couchbase-view

What I want to do is finding all records that match some id and sorted by a name. The data looks something like:

```
{
    type:"receiving",
    saleName:"Harshitha",
    penId:"7aac88118420858d62f5ea55e22"
}
{
    type:"receiving",
    saleName:"Tom",
    penId:"81fb1a79526f4e2bdc77aa7d73d"
}
{
    type:"receiving",
    saleName:"James",
    penId:"81fb1a79526f4e2bdc77aa7d73d"
}
```

I want to get documents with some specific penID sorted by saleName.
Ex:- I want to get documents with this penId ‘81fb1a79526f4e2bdc77aa7d73d’ and sort them by saleName. Like this order:-

```
{
    type:"receiving",
    saleName:"James",
    penId:"81fb1a79526f4e2bdc77aa7d73d"
}
{
    type:"receiving",
    saleName:"Tom",
    penId:"81fb1a79526f4e2bdc77aa7d73d"
}
```

My view like this,

```
View view = database.getView("receiving_view");
  if (view.getMap() == null) {
      view.setMap(new Mapper() {
          @Override
          public void map(Map<String, Object> document, Emitter emitter) {
              if (document.get("type").equals("receiving") ) {

                  List<Object> keys = new ArrayList<Object>();
                  keys.add(document.get("penId"));
                  keys.add(document.get("saleName"));

                  emitter.emit(keys, document);
              }
          }
      }, "1.1");
  }
  return view;
```

Then I tried to get data like this,

```
View view = getView("receiving_view");
Query query = view.createQuery();

List<Object> keys = new ArrayList<Object>();
keys.add("81fb1a79526f4e2bdc77aa7d73d");

List<Object> allKeys = new ArrayList<Object>();
allKeys.add(keys);
query.setKeys(allKeys);
query.run();
```

It’s not working because I passed one key, but their are two keys in the view… But I can’t pass the ‘saleName’ as a key because I want only to sort by ‘saleName’. What is the best way to do this?

Comment: What version of Couchbase Lite?

Comment: Couchbase Lite 1.4.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I found the solution. I don’t want to use setKeys here, I should use range of keys, not a specific set of keys.

I set startKey to `[penID]` and endKey to `[penID, {}]`. The empty map sorts after any other value, so this key range includes all keys that start with `penID`. I change my data getting method. Now this is what it is looks like,

```
View view = getView("receiving_view");
Query query = view.createQuery();

query.setStartKey(Arrays.asList("81fb1a79526f4e2bdc77aa7d73d"));
query.setEndKey(Arrays.asList("81fb1a79526f4e2bdc77aa7d73d", new HashMap<String, Object>()));
query.run();
```